# Workflow of Processing Landsat data for landcover classification

Tags: arcgis-10.1, remote-sensing, interpolation, classification, landsat-8

I have downloaded Landsat-8 data to make a land-use raster.  So far I've made a composite image and clipped it by my study area.  As you can see, there is some slight cloud cover.  I've gone ahead and downloaded L-LDOPE Toolbelt and the same tile during earlier times in the growing season to possibly interpolate the area covered by clouds.

I'm unsure of what to do next.  Should I go ahead and run image classification then go back and account for the clouds or should I deal with the clouds first?  What is the standard work flow for processing these images?  Does anyone know of good background reading on this?  I'm very new to working with Landsat-8 data.  I'm using ArcGIS 10.1.

[image: Watershed with slight cloud cover]

Comment: Why don't start reading about Landsat 8 product and Quality Assessment (QA) band?

Answer (score 4):

Usually you start with cloud (and cloud shadow) removal then you run the classification. One of the best papers I know about cloud detection on Landsat is [Zhu and Woodcock (2012)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0034425711003853)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the paper, which seems very useful.